# Firestore where filter and add data to the result

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i got the following code:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
var duettsRef = db.collection("duetts");

    export const keyExists = (setKey)=>{
      duettsRef.where("key", "==", setKey).where("player2", "==", "").get().then(querySnapshot => {
        console.log(querySnapshot);
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            this.db.collection('duett').set
            ({
              player2: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
          });
            }
        })
    }
```

I logged the snapshot, and its working good untill this point.
The "key" is unique, so the snapshot is either empty or finding one document with this specific properties.
[Screenshot of my firestore structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOxe0.png)
What is not working, that I want if the snapshot is not empty, to edit the "player2" field in the found document, and set it to the current user id.
So for example, if I search for the key:2jskmd21, it would fill the User ID in the player2 field: [Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEmH8.png)
How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation, you will want to use `.update()` rather than `.set()`. This is because the update method is designed to update values in a document while set requires a `merge: true` flag however its primary function is to create a document if it doesn't exist which can be counterproductive.

In this code, I am setting the value as you described and by setting the limit to 1, will retrieve only 1 document.

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
var duettsRef = db.collection("duetts");

    export const keyExists = (setKey)=>{
      duettsRef.where("key", "==", setKey)
       .where("player2", "==", "").limit(1).get()
       .then(querySnapshot => {
        console.log(querySnapshot);
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
                      player2:firebase.auth().currentUser.uid});
            }
        })
       .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
```